# Lifetimes implementing AsRef

Tags: rust

I need to create NewType wrappers for interfacing with FFI. I want to create an interface similar to Rust's String and str types, so I can have a wrapper for an owned type, and a wrapper for a reference. Because some times I'm dealing with references that came from raw pointers that the FFI library will free, and other times I need to take ownership so that rust will free the memory. I want to be able to easily use the methods on the reference type by implementing AsRef on the owned type, but I'm having an issue with lifetimes.

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=91b54c098af8b43ecad3b6671a8dcfe9)

```
pub struct MyInt(i64);

pub struct MyIntRef<'a>(&'a i64);

impl AsRef<MyIntRef<'_>> for MyInt {
    fn as_ref(&self) -> &MyIntRef<'_> {
        todo!()
    }
}
```

This code fails to compile with the following error:

```
= note: expected `fn(&MyInt) -> &MyIntRef<'_>`
           found `fn(&MyInt) -> &MyIntRef<'_>`
```

The error seems to indicate that I do have the correct signature. Why is this failing?

Comment: The immediate problem is that `'_` means two different lifetimes in the two places you have it, but beyond that, how exactly do you intend to fill in that `todo!()`? You can't create a `MyIntRef` inside the function and return a reference to it. Take another look at the relationship between `str` and `String` -- note that neither of them has a lifetime parameter.

Comment: Also, you can look at the implementation of `CString` and `CStr`, (`str` is a primitive type, but `CStr` is pure Rust).

Comment: It would help if you showed how is the C API you are trying to wrap. I'm guessing that the `i64` in your snippets is a placeholder.

Answer (score 1):

I think you've just got your trait parameter type mixed up.

```
pub struct MyInt(i64);

pub struct MyIntRef<'a>(&'a i64);

impl AsRef<i64> for MyInt {
    fn as_ref(&self) -> &i64 {
        &self.0
    }
}

impl<'a> AsRef<i64> for MyIntRef<'a> {
    fn as_ref(&self) -> &i64 {
        self.0
    }
}
```